# The application does not see xib file in the bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I put 2 xib file in bundle. And this bundle added to the project by dragging and dropping. When `[super initWithNibName: @ "RUIBrowser.bundle / RUIBrowseriPhoneView.xib" bundle: nil];`
app crashes with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle:' NSBundle  (loaded) 'with name' RUIBrowser.bundle /
>   RUIBrowseriPhoneView.xib'

What did I do wrong?

[image: Added bundle]

Comment: try `NSBundle * RUIbundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:absolutePath];` and use `initWithNibName:@"RUIBrowseriPhoneView" bundle:RUIbundle`

Comment: You should use this naming convention: RUIBrowserView~ipad.xib and RUIBrowserView~iphone.xib. Then you just write initWithNibName:@"RUIBrowserView" in your code

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. It was very simple

```
NSBundle *bundle = [[NSBundle alloc] initWithPath:@"RUIBrowser.bundle"];
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"RUIBrowseriPadView" bundle:bundle];
} else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"RUIBrowseriPhoneView" bundle:bundle];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to initialize the nib.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    [super initWithNibName:@"RUIBrowseriPhoneView" bundle: nil];
}
else
{
    [super initWithNibName:@"RUIBrowseriPadView" bundle: nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

find your nib path :

```
NSLog(@"nib path from bundle: %@", [self.yourNibBundle pathForResource:@"RUIBrowseriPhoneView" ofType:@"nib"]);

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:pathNibFile].

    UIViewController *viewController = [[yourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RUIBrowseriPhoneView" bundle:bundle];
```